# Build Error with custom keyboard (app extension) - Invalid Entitlement

Tags: xcode, keyboard, ios-app-extension, entitlements, ios-app-group

I'm building a custom keyboard app. I made 2 separate App IDs and provisioning profiles for each -  the app and the extension. I added 'app group' capability to both on Member center portal. Then in Xcode, I enabled App group capability for both targets. I'm getting the following error while building this on my iPhone:

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

[image]

Comment: Don't use "please help", it doesn't help anything. But if you ask with perfect spelling, it helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks for comment but being a semantic / spelling police doesn't help either. Specially if you are not going to answer the question. When I make a request, I say please. When someone responds to my request, I say thank you. Have a good day/night.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should go the target of your app and check there with your host application. Might be you are assigning wrong provision profile or mis matching with the bundle id some where.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loKZz.png)

Comment: Host application only appears for Test and UITest. Not for App extensions.